# switch / rotate images based on device orientation (landscape / portrait)

Tags: craft3, plugin-imager

I have the feeling I'm the only one with such complicated code for my images.
With so many devices with different view ports and landscape / portrait...

How do you all handle your picture tag art-direction responsive stuff?

Now i want some images to be rotated if the device is in portrait mode.
Imager has no transform for rotate. So i need to upload the rotated image and set it as alternative to the other image.

**Edit:**
The code i have now after changing it:

```
{% if entry.textImages | length %}

  {% for row in entry.textImages.all() %}

    {% set image = row.textImage.one() %}
    {% set imageWidth = row.textImageWidth %}
    {% set imageHeight = row.textImageHeight %}
    {% set imageClass = row.textImageClass %}

    {% set imagePortrait = row.textImagePortrait.one() %}

    {% set imageType = row.textImageType.value %}
    {% set fileName = image.filename|trim('.' ~ image.extension, 'right') %}

    {% set tempImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image, { width: 2000 },
      {
        allowUpscale: false,
        resizeFilter: 'lanczos',
        effects: { unsharpMask: [0, 0.55, 0.55, 0.008] },
        interlace: false,
        convertToRGB: true
      }
    ) %}

    {% if imageHeight is not empty %}
      {% set tempHeight = tempImage.getHeight() %}
      {% set imageSizes = [{ height: tempHeight },
                           { height: imageHeight * 4.5 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 4.25 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 4 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 3.75 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 3.5 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 3.25 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 3 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 2.75 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 2.5 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 2.25 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 2 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 1.75 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 1.5 },
                           { height: imageHeight * 1.25 },
                           { height: imageHeight }] %}
    {% else %}
      {% set tempWidth = tempImage.getWidth() %}
      {% set imageSizes = [{ width: tempWidth },
                           { width: imageWidth * 4.5 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 4.25 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 4 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 3.75 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 3.5 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 3.25 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 3 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 2.75 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 2.5 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 2.25 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 2 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 1.75 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 1.5 },
                           { width: imageWidth * 1.25 },
                           { width: imageWidth }] %}
    {% endif %}

    {% set transformedImages = craft.imager.transformImage(tempImage, imageSizes,
      {
        format: imageType,
        allowUpscale: false,
        resizeFilter: 'lanczos',
        effects: { unsharpMask: [0, 0.55, 0.55, 0.008] },
        interlace: false,
        convertToRGB: true,
        filenamePattern: fileName ~ '_{fullname|hash}.{extension}'
      }
    ) %}

    {% set transformedImagesWidth = transformedImages[15].getWidth() %}
    {% set imagePortraitSizes = [{ width: transformedImagesWidth * 4.5 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 4.25 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 4 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 3.75 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 3.5 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 3.25 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 3 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 2.75 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 2.5 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 2.25 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 2 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 1.75 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 1.5 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth * 1.25 },
                                 { width: transformedImagesWidth }] %}

    {% set transformedPortraitImages = craft.imager.transformImage(imagePortrait, imagePortraitSizes,
      {
        format: imageType,
        allowUpscale: false,
        resizeFilter: 'lanczos',
        effects: { unsharpMask: [0, 0.55, 0.55, 0.008] },
        interlace: false,
        convertToRGB: true
      }
    ) %}

    <picture>
      {% if imagePortrait is not empty %}
        <source media="(orientation: portrait)"
                sizes="80vw"
                srcset="{{ craft.imager.srcset(transformedPortraitImages) }}">
      {% endif %}
      <img class="anchor {% if imageClass is not empty %}{{ imageClass }}{% endif %}"
           src="{{ transformedImages[15].getUrl() }}"
           sizes="{% if row.textImageVW is not empty %}
                    (orientation: portrait) {{ row.textImageVW }}vw,
                    (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 799px) {{ row.textImageVW }}vw,
                  {% else %}
                    (orientation: portrait) 80vw,
                    (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 799px) 60vw,
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if imageHeight is not empty %}{{ transformedImagesWidth }}{% else %}{{ imageWidth }}{% endif %}px"
           srcset="{{ craft.imager.srcset(transformedImages) }}"
           title="{{ image.title }}"
           alt="{{ image.altText }}">
    </picture>

  {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

And this is a entry:
[image]

To calculate the width for the portrait view image i use the width of the transformed landscape image (transformedImagesWidth).
The reason is that the images should align.

You can see it here:
[Phantasialand Hörspiel & Videokassetten](https://skulltronics.net/phantasialand-hoerspiel-und-videokassetten)
On a PC you see the case and two tapes in one row.
On a phone they are one below the other and the tapes rotate.

Only thing i don't like right now is that if i rotate the phone to landscape that i get the landscape image. But below 800px it should still show the portrait image.

Comment: I think you are over-complicating things. Why not just crop the image to different proportions for different size screens? Alternatively, If you really do think you need to rotate the image, and I can't see why you would, do it with css by simply adding a class like `.rotate-90` as required.

Comment: @Seth Warburton i need to rotate because it makes no sense to crop a cassette/vhs tape. I tried it with CSS but only CSS does not work without JavaScript to recalculate the viewport.

Comment: Re-calulate the viewport?? Just use add height and width attrs to your `<img`, no reflow, no .js required.

Comment: @SethWarburton How do you know height and width? In sizes you set vw and in CSS you can only use %. If i rotate in CSS on "@media all and (orientation:portrait)" the picture goes over the edges of the screen. Also setting 80% there will not work because that is 80% of the image and not screen. Also that way the browser will not download the smaller image (bandwidth). Isn't the picture tag not for delivering different art-direction?

Comment: @Seth Warburton Also JS would not work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#Why_cant_we_just_do_this_using_CSS_or_JavaScript

Comment: How do you know the height and width?? Ask Craft, width="{{ asset.getWidth() }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight() }}"> as detailed in the docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/image-transforms.html#defining-transforms-in-your-templates

Comment: @Seth Warburton height and width of the viewport/device. Did you read the Mozilla article...

Comment: Yo have completely misunderstood me @MrGlasspoole, I was trying to help but am giving up now. No need to read the article because 1) I am intimately familiar with how responsive images work and b) I already have a performant responsive image solution in Craft which is easy to use, easy to implement, and works perfectly.

Comment: @Seth Warburton I appreciate your help. But i wonder how you do it if Mozilla says it can't be done with CSS because then the image is already downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

## 1.

If you need a rotated version of an image but Imager can't transform the image programmatically, you could just create **2 different asset fields** for the same image. One field for the landscape orientation, and the other for portrait.

In that table view example you showed above I'd imagine you would need 2 columns: **Image Landscape** and **Image Portrait**.

You could access those images in your template with something like this:

```
{% for row in entry.textImages.all() %}

  {% set imagePortrait = row.textImagePortrait.one() ?? null %}
  {% set imageLandscape = row.textImageLandscape.one() ?? null %}

  {% if imagePortrait %}
    ...
  {% endif %}

  {% if imageLandscape %}
    ...
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

---

## 2.

If you want to swap out a different images (size, cropping, orientation, etc) you need "[art direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#Art_direction)."

`sizes` and `srcset` attribtues work together to help the browser choose the right resolution image. But ultimately it's up to the browser which image to use.

The `picture` and `source` tags *explicitly* tell the browser what to do based on the `media` attribute. *"Browser do this..."*

Here's the most basic example of serving a different image for portrait orientation (landscape is the default):

```
<picture>
  <source media="(orientation: portrait)" srcset="portrait.jpg">
  <img src="landscape.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

Codepen example: [Art direction image with orientation, simple](https://codepen.io/alexroper/pen/ExYpvVR?editors=1000)

Then you can add on different sizes a resolutions to each source by expanding on `srcset` and `sizes`.

```
<picture>
    <source media="(orientation: portrait)"
            srcset="portrait.jpg 400w,
                    portrait-md.jpg 600w,
                    portrait-lg.jpg 800w" 
            sizes="(min-width: 400px) 400px,
                   100vw">
    <img src="landscape.jpg"
         srcset="landscape.jpg 600w,
                 landscape-md.jpg 800w,
                 landscape-lg.jpg 1200w"
         sizes="(min-width: 600px) 600px,
                100vw"
         alt="">
</picture>
```

Codepen example: [Art direction image with orientation, complex](https://codepen.io/alexroper/pen/vYBaZMP?editors=1000)

In that example, both images start out 100% of the viewport width on small screens. But the portrait image doesn't get larger than 400px wide, and the landscape image doesn't get larger than 600px.

---

## 3.

Since you have to transform 2 images with similar options, there's a few ways you can optimize this.

You can store your array of options to reuse:

```
{% set imageOptions = {
  format: imageType,
  allowUpscale: false,
  resizeFilter: 'lanczos',
  effects: { unsharpMask: [0, 0.55, 0.55, 0.008] },
  interlace: false,
  convertToRGB: true,
  filenamePattern: fileName ~ '_{fullname|hash}.{extension}'
} %}
```

You can use the [`fillTransforms`](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft#filltransforms-bool) option in Imager to fill in sizes between your min an max size.

```
{# Taken from Imager docs #}
{% set transformedImages = craft.imager.transformImage(image, [
    { width: 1200 }, 
    { width: 400 }
    ], { ratio: 16/9, position: image.getFocalPoint() }, 
    { fillTransforms: true }) %}
```

Here's what this might look like when you output the image:

```
{% set transformedPortraitImages = craft.imager.transformImage(imagePortrait, [
    { height: 2000 },
    { height: 400 }
  ], imageOptions, { fillTransforms: true }) %}

{% set transformedLandscapeImages = craft.imager.transformImage(imageLandscape, [
    { width: 2000 },
    { width: 400 }
  ], imageOptions, { fillTransforms: true }) %}


<picture>
    {% if imagePortrait %}
      <source media="(orientation: portrait)"
              srcset="{{ craft.imager.srcset(transformedPortraitImages) }}"
              sizes="...">
    {% endif %}  
    <img src="{{ transformedLandscapeImages[(transformedLandscapeImages|length - 1)].url }}"
         srcset="{{ craft.imager.srcset(transformedLandscapeImages) }}"
         sizes="..."
         alt="">
</picture>
```

This code may not meet your needs completely, but hopefully this is enough to set you on the right path.

Comment: The problem is more how to handle it in Craft than the HTML. I also thought about the second column. Problem is then a can not set extra style/css on that image. Also i'm not sure how to get the image from the second column (code). Something like this would be nice: https://i.imgur.com/i0ahCeM.jpg

Comment: Okay, I added an example of accessing 2 images in a row in the template.

Comment: What does the "?? null" do? First time i see it. That way it means i have to put the Imager code twice in my template. Also I'm not sure if the width and height settings also work on the portrait images.

Comment: `??` is the null-coalescing operator. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators. It prevents errors when calling a method like .one() if there isn't asset selected. Here's an excellent explanation of how and why to use it: https://straightupcraft.com/events/twigs-null-coalescing-operator

Comment: Yes, you would transform both portrait and landscape images. I can add some suggestions for simplifying that.

Comment: I updated my question how i did it now. A view weeks ago i was playing with "fillTransforms" but it did not work how i wanted it. Can't remember why i did it how i do it now. Problem left for now is the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: To show the portrait image below 800px as well try `media="(orientation: portrait), (max-width: 799px)"`. That gets evaluated like an "or" statement. It matches if either in portrait orientation or the viewport is less than 800px.

Comment: That way the rotated picture is to width if the phone is landscape because the other images are only 60vw in landscape and below 799px. If i omit "media" and do sizes="(orientation: portrait) 80vw, (max-width: 799px) 60vw" i have the rotated image also on my PC (though the desktop is more than 799?).

Comment: Seems like i have to set both. media="(orientation: portrait), (max-width: 799px)" and sizes="(orientation: portrait) 80vw, (max-width: 799px) 60vw". If i omit "media" i get the rotated image on the desktop.